# Show activity as Dialog is displaying two dialogs

Tags: android, android-dialog

Requirement :  I want to disply dialog when timezone is changed,I folled below steps

Output : It is displaying 2 dialogs (See at the end for dialog images what I am getting)

Expected Output : I want to display only one image,I don't want to  display "Application Name"  as another dialog (ie) dialog -2.Any help??

**Step-1].Create Broadcast Receiver in manifest file**

```
 <receiver android:name=".common.TimeReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED"/>
  </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

**Step-2].Write code to display dialog if timezone is changed,[From some websites I came to know that from BroadcastReceiver ,we cant display dialog.so i am using activity for showing dialog]**

```
public class TimeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent in = new Intent(context, TimeActivity.class);
        in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(in);
    }
}
```

**Step-3].Create Activity in manifest file**

```
 <activity android:name="TimeActivity"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
```

**Step-4].Create Layout file for Activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Your Zone is Changed" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/okbutton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/string_ook" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Step-5]. code to display dialog in Activity**

```
public class TimeActivity extends Activity {
    Button ok;
    Dialog d ;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    d = new Dialog(this);
    d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    d.setContentView(R.layout.timezonechanged);
    d.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    ok = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.okbutton);
    d.show();
        ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            d.cancel();
            }
    });
    }}
```

**OUTPUT:**

**dialog - 1 :**

[image]

**dialog - 2 :**(Just consider my app names is "DialogApp")

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In activity class,I did changes like below,Now it is working,Thanks to  user1688181

```
public class TimeActivity extends Activity {
    Button ok;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.timezonechanged);
        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okbutton);

    ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest simply make your activity declaration like this ..

```
 <activity android:name="app.kleward.ecocabs.utils.GPSDialogActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
         />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using activity as a dialog and add dialog to that activity. that is the problem.
remove the dialog form the code.just use the acticty as follows.

```
public class TimeActivity extends Activity {
Button ok;
Dialog d ;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.timezonechanged);

    ok = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.okbutton);

    ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        d.cancel();
        }
});
}}
```

Comment: Application Name is displayed as second dialog ,I didnt write any code for this one..I dont know how this dialog is coming..u told me to use **this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);**,I am already using **d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);** here d is dialog object..Is there any difference between above two ?

Comment: I replaced **d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);** with **this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);**,But I am getting dialog with out Application name.any idea ??

Comment: yo declared TimeZoneActivity activity as dialog. is that the right class what about the TimeActivity ? it should be TimeActivity isn't it.

Comment: ok then my answer will help you.you trying to activity as dialog and dialog inside that activity.use only activity. remove dialog.